# MVC Model Property by string Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

A common way to fill a table is:

```
@For Each item In Model
   Dim currentItem = item
   @<tr>
      <td>currentitem.Data1</td>
      <td>currentitem.Data2</td>
      <td>currentitem.Data3</td>
   </tr>
Next
```

But for some reasons (to control the order of columns), I would like to refer to the fields by their string names, something like this:

```
@For Each item In Model
   Dim currentItem = item
   @<tr>
      <td>currentitem("Data1").Value</td>
      <td>currentitem("Data2").Value</td>
      <td>currentitem("Data3").Value</td>
   </tr>
Next
```

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: That's not how you would refer to a model item.  The only way this would be possible is to make your model a `Dictionary<string, object>`. With that said, your reason makes no sense.  What do you mean 'control the order of columns` - you can do that with the strongly typed model just as easily.

Comment: Tommy, Thank you. Yes, it is a stupid question, but I thought I could do it this way.

Comment: is not a stupid question.  I just am having trouble understanding why you would want to go about it this way.  I ask because if we understand better why you want to do this, we could possibly show you a better/different way than using loosely typed variables like you are asking.

Comment: For example, in one case, I have to show the columns in the following order (data1,data2,data3), in another case (data2,data3,data1). As I understand the better way to do it in the controller, but is it possible to change it in the view?

Comment: If your properties are as you have described, it would be hard to make it clean.  If instead you had a collection of `Data` you could control the order of the items in the collection in the controller and iterate over each item (without using a string name) in your view.  Alternatively if you have pre-defined column orders, you could create multiple partial views and conditionally render them based on which order is needed.

Comment: I receive my data from the dataset. Columns are data1...data25. I would like to have the possibility to hide some columns and show them in various positions (ordering). Of course it can't be predefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - now that we have established that you need to change the order of your view model, let's do a little bit of work to your view model to make it easier to change the order.  Given that we have to change the order of how we display things, we have to have a way to track what order to display them in.  To change on the fly in the view without having different views with different orders (could get messy fast) - so let's just update our model a little bit.

Let assume this is your view model

```
public class OriginalViewModel{
    public string Data1 {get;set;}
    public string Data2 {get;set;}
    public string Data3 {get;set;|
}
```

Let's create a new class called DataProperty.  This will hold the data objects as well as allow us to set a display order that we can sort on later.

```
public class DataProperty{
    public int DisplayOrder {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

Now, let's update your view model to be a set of these DataProperties.  We are using something we can enumerate and order by the display order.

```
public class UpdatedViewModel{
   public IEnumerable<DataProperty> DataSet {get;set;}
}
```

Now, you can set the display order on each one of your property elements.

```
var listOfItems = new List<DataProperty>();
listOfItems.Add(new DataProperty{Data = "data1", DisplayOrder = 2});
listOfItems.Add(new DataProperty{Data = "data2", DisplayOrder = 3});
listOfItems.Add(new DataProperty{Data = "data3", DisplayOrder = 1});
var model = new UpdatedViewModel();
model.Data = listOfItems;
```

In your view, order by the display order property.  Note we can now use Linq to order our data appropriately based on the requirements for this view.

```
@{foreach(var item in Model.OrderBy(x=>x.Data.DisplayOrder){
   <tr>
      <td>@item.Data</td>
      <td>@item.Data</td>
      <td>@item.Data</td>
   </tr>
}}
```

which should render in HTML

```
<tr>
   <td>data3</td>
   <td>data1</td>
   <td>data2</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **Tommy**,

I tried to solve it in simple way and did this:

For example, I have a Viewdata that contains the order of the columns:

```
ViewData("columnsorder")="|3|1|2|"
```

and then, I just loop through ViewData and set the columns.

```
@For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item
    @<tr>
    @For i As Integer = 1 To ViewData("columnsorder").ToString.Split("|").Count - 2
            Dim ind As Integer = ViewData("columnsorder").ToString.Split("|")(i)
            Select Case ind
                Case 1@<td>@currentItem.Data1</td>
                Case 2@<td>@currentItem.Data2</td>
                Case 3@<td>@currentItem.Data3</td>
            End Select
    Next
    </tr>
Next
```